# Объявление метода класса в SystemVerilog

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog

Всем привет!
Мне нужен кейс, где класс объявляется внутри другого класса, и имеет какой-либо метод.
Позже этот метод вызывается после классов непосредственно перед модулем

```
class packet;
  class child;
    bit [31:0] addr;
    bit [31:0] data;
    
  extern virtual function void display();
 
  endclass
endclass

function void packet::display();
  $display("Addr = %0d Data = %0d",addr,data);
endfunction

module child_method;
  initial begin
    packet::child::display c;
    c = new();
    c.addr = 30;
    c.data = 40;
  end
endmodule
```

Вот пример кода, кто то подскажет в чем ошибка ?